# How would you make a button add text/a header/a paragraph on-click?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have my button ready, I just don't know what would I write using javascript to make it show text (instead of an alert) on-click.

```html
<button onclick="text()">Show text</button>
```

How should I code that text function in javascript so when I press the button it adds, for example, a paragraph which says: Button worked (I can style it myself).

If anybody is wondering what I am attempting to do, it's a quiz with really basic answers (just trying html, css & javascript for fun). Whenever you click one of my existing buttons (that represent the possible answers), you get an alert:

```js
alert("Correct answer");
```

for example ^. I just want it to show "Correct answer" as text instead of having it show as a pop-up.

Answer (score 1):

Just use the [textContent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/textContent) property to add text on click like this:

```js
const btn = document.getElementById('someBtnId');
const someHeader = document.getElementById('someHeader');

btn.addEventListener('click', function() {
  someHeader.textContent="Your Custom Text Here";
});
```

```html
<button id="someBtnId">Show text</button>
<h1 id="someHeader"></h1>
```

Or if you want to add an element (like the `h1` element in the above snippet) dynamically on click, you can just use [template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) to create the element and the [innerHTML](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/innerHTML) property to add the element to the DOM like this:

```js
const btn = document.getElementById('someBtnId');

btn.addEventListener('click', function() {
  const x = `<h1 id="someHeader">Your Custom Text Here</h1>`;
  document.body.innerHTML += x;
});
```

```html
<button id="someBtnId">Show text</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [`document.createElement`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/createElement) and [`Node.appendChild`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/appendChild).

```js
const listen = event => {
  const p = document.createElement('p');
  p.innerText = "The button worked!";
  document.querySelector('#container').appendChild(p);
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <button onclick="listen()" id="button">Click me</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score -2):

const HandleUpclick = () => {
let newText = text.toUpperCase()
setText(newText)

Convert to Uppercase

// for converting lower case words to uppercase in JSX //